# Capturing Java https through Fiddler and getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, fiddler, keystore, keytool

I am trying to capture http/https traffic through Fiddler. Here's my java VM configuration:

```
-DproxySet=true  -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1  -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1  -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/home/matej/FiddlerKeystore"  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="password" -Djavax.net.debug=all -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -Dsun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages=true
```

And below is the program output:

```
/home/App/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:60328,suspend=y,server=n -Dvisualvm.id=10480198847735 -DproxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/FiddlerKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.debug=all -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -Dsun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath ...(classpath)
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60328', transport: 'socket'
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
trustStore is: /home/FiddlerKeystore
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot, O=DO_NOT_TRUST_BC, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com
  Issuer:  CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot, O=DO_NOT_TRUST_BC, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xab65de924a48c2396134e2defb4d91
  Valid from Fri Feb 24 01:00:00 CET 2017 until Wed Mar 03 02:19:48 CET 2027

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom

GET https://something.com HTTP/1.1
Parameters:
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1471958467 bytes = { 192, 249, 190, 201, 30, 121, 120, 147, 168, 43, 222, 98, 184, 184, 234, 131, 148, 63, 147, 79, 106, 122, 203, 88, 178, 140, 148, 113 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 197
0000: 01 00 00 C1 03 03 58 BC   4E C3 C0 F9 BE C9 1E 79  ......X.N......y
0010: 78 93 A8 2B DE 62 B8 B8   EA 83 94 3F 93 4F 6A 7A  x..+.b.....?.Ojz
0020: CB 58 B2 8C 94 71 00 00   3A C0 23 C0 27 00 3C C0  .X...q..:.#.'.<.
0030: 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  %.).g.@...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2B C0   2F 00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00  ..3.2.+./...-.1.
0050: 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00   0A C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00  ................
0060: 13 00 FF 01 00 00 5E 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......^...4.2...
0070: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0080: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0090: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
00A0: 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D 00   1C 00 1A 06 03 06 01 05  ................
00B0: 03 05 01 04 03 04 01 04   02 03 03 03 01 03 02 02  ................
00C0: 03 02 01 02 02                                     .....
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 197
[Raw write]: length = 202
0000: 16 03 03 00 C5 01 00 00   C1 03 03 58 BC 4E C3 C0  ...........X.N..
0010: F9 BE C9 1E 79 78 93 A8   2B DE 62 B8 B8 EA 83 94  ....yx..+.b.....
0020: 3F 93 4F 6A 7A CB 58 B2   8C 94 71 00 00 3A C0 23  ?.Ojz.X...q..:.#
0030: C0 27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29   00 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13  .'.<.%.).g.@....
0040: 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33   00 32 C0 2B C0 2F 00 9C  ./.....3.2.+./..
0050: C0 2D C0 31 00 9E 00 A2   C0 08 C0 12 00 0A C0 03  .-.1............
0060: C0 0D 00 16 00 13 00 FF   01 00 00 5E 00 0A 00 34  ...........^...4
0070: 00 32 00 17 00 01 00 03   00 13 00 15 00 06 00 07  .2..............
0080: 00 09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B   00 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E  ................
0090: 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00 02   00 12 00 04 00 05 00 14  ................
00A0: 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00 02   01 00 00 0D 00 1C 00 1A  ................
00B0: 06 03 06 01 05 03 05 01   04 03 04 01 04 02 03 03  ................
00C0: 03 01 03 02 02 03 02 01   02 02                    ..........
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
main, called closeSocket()
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:388)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at mobile.KRAHttpClient.get(KRAHttpClient.java:77)
    at mobile.Bettor.verifyIntegrity(Bettor.java:313)
    at mobile.Bettor.verifyAndLogin(Bettor.java:592)
    at webapp.Main.main(Main.java:46)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    ... 19 more
```

As you can see FiddlerKeystore is successfully loaded. However I am still getting `SSLHandshakeException`. What could be causing this please? Thank you. :)

Comment: You are trying to intercept your https traffic. Java detects this and gives you an error, since the https conversation is not secure.

Comment: Nulano, thanks for your comment. I am giving java a certificate to trust, that should mean fiddler is trusted authority and https traffic should be decrypted with no problems. I dont think this is the cause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is "simple".
You need to export the Fiddler certificate and add it to the cacert or jsssecacerts ($JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security).

You create the fiddler certificate by using
tools --> options -> https --> actions --> Export Root certificate to Desktop

Example of command

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\keytool" -importcert -file <Your path to Fiddler certificate>\fiddler root.cert -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\lib\security\jssecacerts" -storepass changeit
```